# Connect to special instance of SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, connection-string, sql-server-2000

I have 2 SQL Server instances on my machine, one 2000 and one 2008.

The SQL Server 2000 instance is called `MSSQLServer` and the SQL Server 2008 instance is called `MSSQLServer2008`.

Now I want to connect to `MSSQLServer` (version 2000) with ASP.Net and I'm using this connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>    
    <add name="myConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=MyServerIP,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDBName;uid=MyUsername;pwd=MyPasword;Trusted_Connection=False;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and when I want to connect to the database I get this error :

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I used `MyServerIP\Instancename,1433;` but I get error again.

What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can set different ports for each instance. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/823938 for details.

Also, make sure you have enabled TCP/IP connections for these instances. The KB provides the details as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check for Firewall Settings,Port allocation and TCP/IP Connection settings. One of all these should be a culprit.